# JavaScript append multiple in for loop

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with the append?

```
function filterPosts(){
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('search-filter').value.toUpperCase();

  let posts = document.getElementById('posts');

  let post = posts.querySelectorAll('div.post');

  for (let i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
    let filterItem = post[i].getElementsByTagName('h5')[0];
    if (filterItem.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
        post[i].append();
    } else {
        post[i].remove();
      
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a few different things to no avail. I'm trying to remove elements based on type and then readd them if they exist based on heading.

Comment: Append… what? You didn’t say.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In vanilla javascript use `target.appendChild(element)`

Comment: I have divs classed as post within a div ID of posts. They include an h5 within posts. They are being triggered to be filtered based off of a dropdown which I have working, but I am also trying to ensure that if someone types out something, and it matches the h5 element, those posts will remain, while the rest will be deleted from the DOM, and vise-versa, if someone decides to backspace on the textbox, it should show all posts.

Comment: You have to add parameters to `append`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: Looks like you want only the `else` block, since the post starts out by being there (appended), so nothing to do then... You should only remove.

Comment: Running into an issue now if the textbox is empty, or backspaced it will not bring back all posts, i was using display: inline and display: none before and it worked but i can't use it with AOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
    let filterItem = post[i].getElementsByTagName('h5')[0];
    if (filterItem.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
        posts.appendChild(post[i]);
    } else {
        post[i].remove();
    }
  }
```

This ended up working for the filtering, but it doesnt bring back posts if textbox is backspaced or empty.

Answer (score 0):

you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild (has better browser support than append) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild - in your case  this would looks like `posts.appendChild(post[i])` and `posts.removeChild(post[i])`

you could also just change the visibility of the elements - this should be faster and simpler for your case.
another way would be to have an array with the all the posts data and work with it primarily. this way you can also "bring back the data".
each time the filter changes: create a new array by filtering the posts data, remove all post elements, then append only those that match the filtered data e.g.

```
let postsData = ["content1", "content2"];
for (let i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
  post[i].remove();
}
postsData.filter(function (post) {
 return post.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1;
}).forEach(function () {
  var postElem = document.createElement("div");
  posts.appendChild(postElem);
});
```